# Poisson delay formula/function for VB?

Tags: vb.net, poisson

I have a requirement where in I need to sleep for a Poisson duration before sending the next packet. The current formula I can think of is

```
( e^(-lambda) X lambda^t ) / fact(t)
```

However, for time steps 280 and more the fact(t) would become obsolete due to overflow.

Can someone help me workaround this conventional way in VB .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the inter-arrival time. A random inter-arrival time can be generated using

```
t = (Math.log(1.0-Math.random())/-lambda
```

The formula you posted is the one that defines the ***probability*** that there are exactly t (in your case) arrivals within a specific time period.

See the Wikipedia article on [generating Poisson distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Generating_Poisson-distributed_random_variables).

Answer (score 0):

Even though the factorial value is getting extremely large (as you've observed), the λ <sup>k</sup> term is also getting somewhat large to compensate.  For a way to represent the distribution that takes this into account, see [the Wikipedia article on the Poisson distribution:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Evaluating_the_Poisson_Distribution)

[image]

A VB implementation might look something like:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine(Poisson(4, 250))
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

    Function Poisson(ByVal lambda As Integer, ByVal k As Integer) As Double
        Poisson = Math.Exp(k * Math.Log(lambda) - lambda - SumOverLn(1, k))
    End Function

    Function SumOverLn(ByVal start As Integer, ByVal endval As Integer) As Long
        Dim i As Integer
        SumOverLn = 0
        For i = start To endval
            SumOverLn = SumOverLn + Math.Log(i)
        Next

    End Function

End Module
```

It looks like after a while it is so close to 0 that it registers as such.  You may be able to adjust the precision of the display to get more decimal places, but 0 might be a decent enough approximation for high values (the notion that you get from the probability theory seems to be that those values are indeed very close to zero anyway).